# How to set CTEST_SOURCE_DIRECTORY

Tags: cmake, ctest

I am trying to setup CTest to run a coverage analysis. It seems like I have to make a MyScript.cmake file and call it with `ctest -S MyScript.cmake`. I thought a simple example might look like this:

```
ctest_start(TestCoverage)
ctest_coverage(BUILD ${CTEST_BINARY_DIRECTORY})
```

but I am getting

```
ctest_start source directory not specified.  Specify source directory as an argument or set CTEST_SOURCE_DIRECTORY
```

I don't want to hard code this path in the script file as I may want to run it in different places, so where am I supposed to get paths for `CTEST_SOURCE_DIRECTORY` and `CTEST_BINARY_DIRECTORY`?

Comment: How do you call `cmake`? If you call it manually, you can add the variable like `cmake -DCTEST_SOURCE_DIRECTORY=<somePath> -DCTEST_BINARY_DIRECTORY=<someOtherPath>`

Comment: @usr1234567 You can pass those options with `ctest -S`?

Comment: No, I wanted you to use "-D <var>:<type>=<value>
Define a variable for script mode" See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/manual/ctest.1.html